# SOP highlighting a change in career path

Tags: statement-of-purpose, management

I am eager to pursue a postgraduate diploma course in supply chain management, a path I believe aligns perfectly with my analytical thinking capabilities. Now I neither have relevant experience nor an undergraduate degree in the field. With a BA in human resource management and over 6 years of experience in content writing, I have honed my skills in crafting website copies and blogs for reputable online directories. While transitioning to a career in supply chain management, I recognize the value of my transferable skills and am determined to leverage them effectively. As I embark on this journey, I am committed to conveying my genuine reasons for this career change in my Statement of Purpose. I would greatly appreciate any insights you can provide to help me construct a compelling SOP for the university I am targeting. Also, I have a 2-year gap right after my graduation mainly cz I have to be there for my mother who was battling a serious health condition and needed constant care. Although I did do some odd jobs, but I believe it would do me a disservice to disclose it on my sop. Can I instead divulge this personal detain on an sop?